# Is it possible to autoexecute a javascript on tab opening?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I explain better: i'm growing my community on facebook asking friends to invite other friends with this link

https://m.facebook.com/send_page_invite/?pageid=MYPAGEID

I'm wondering if could i insert this url inside an iframe and auto-execute the script i use for invite all friends

*--- javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('CLASS-NAMES'); for(var i=0;i

on tab opening.

I hope my English is sufficiently understandable, and thank you all

Comment: Probably not. CORS will deny it.

Comment: Plus, Facebook will probably consider it spam, if they see you sending out such invites en masse.

Comment: Not probably. It will definitely be considered spam. And your page will most likely be banned

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is to track tabs, if user clicked a link with blank on it, then add some value to a session, or to href parameter, and then manualy check if he came from a new tab or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want FB invite friend in an iFrame you have 
to initiate the facebook Connect API first and for this we need XFBML initialization in the bottom of the page.

You should use fb:serverfbml tag to get fb:friend-selector working.

assuming this is your iframe body content

```
<fb:serverfbml style="width: 650px;"> 
<script type="text/fbml">
<fb:fbml> 
    <fb:request-form
        action="http://your-site.com/invite/sent"
        method="POST"
        invite="true"
        type="My App"
        content="download my application FREE NOW"
            <fb:req-choice url='http://your- 
facebook-canvas-url'
            label='<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars("Accept button text",ENT_QUOTES); 
?>'
            /> 
        " > 
        <fb:multi-friend-selector
            showborder="false"
            actiontext="Invite your friends."
            exclude_ids="optional"
            rows="3"
        /> 
    </fb:request-form> 
   </fb:fbml>
</script> 
</fb:serverfbml>
```

//this script up will display the invite friend on the //iFrame tag .

//to connect use  FB.connect code

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB_RequireFeatures(
    ["CanvasUtil"],
    function(){

FB.XdComm.Server.init('/xd_receiver.html');

FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent();
    }
);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ 
FB.Facebook.init("write your api key authintication 
here", "/xd_receiver.html"); });   
</script>
```

Comment: this looks like some very old code. are you sure it still works? for example. that static link does not. fbml is gone since many years already, where did you find this?

Comment: it was a working example on codepen.io m i usually write reference link but eh !! human we are

Comment: can you add the codepen link? i would be very surprised if this works.

Comment: oh man , i have 20 TB librarry on my pc , its all different questions from different websites organized on different folders so , i am not sure what the date of the file cus when i scan them with anti virus it updates the folder date . alright then  , to avoid any conflict  let me  implement this example for you , this way we will feel better .. allow me some times i just came off work ..  :)

Comment: i thought that it was a working example on codepen, not on your computer? you should not post very old code without testing, especially when it comes to facebook. it is not even an answer to the question, he wants to do auto-invites - which is not allowed anyway.

Comment: sorry i will work on it once i finished something on my hand soon i promise